# 2 checkbox when both check provide new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three div when I want to use checkbox should I have new div 
if I check car1 while car2 unchecked should I have red car 
but if check car1 while car2 checked should I have black car

```
<div id="carblack">
    car black
</div>
<div id="carred"  style="display:none">
    car red
</div>
<div id="carblue"  style="display:none">
    car blue
</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="car1" name="vehicle" value="red" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" id="car2" name="vehicle1" value="blue"  checked/>
```

```js
$('#car1').change(function () {

    if($(this).attr("checked")){
        document.getElementById("carred").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("carblack").style.display = "none";
    } else{
        document.getElementById("carblack").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("carred").style.display = "none";
    }
});

$('#car2').change(function () {

    if($(this).attr("checked")){
        document.getElementById("carblue").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("carblack").style.display = "none";
    } else{
        document.getElementById("carblack").style.display = "block"; 
        document.getElementById("carblue").style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please rephrase your question? i could not understand it! moreover, you don't need to use `document.getElementById..` while you are using jQuey. Use like: `$('#carred').css('display', 'block')`

Comment: I mean how I can 2 checkboxs when they checked give me car black also,when each one checked alone give me its car

Comment: I think know what do you want and and i change my post check out maybe helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 radio checked or none of them - black?

```
$(function(){
    var cars = $('div[id^="car"]'),
        inputs = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

    inputs.change(function(){
        cars.hide();
        if(inputs.filter(':checked').length === 1)
        {
           cars.filter('#car' + $(this).val()).show();
        }
        else {
           cars.filter('#carblack').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jAxHT/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#car1').change(function () {

if($(this).attr("checked")){
    if($(this).next().attr("checked")){
    document.getElementById("carblack").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("carred").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("carblue").style.display = "none";
    }else{
    document.getElementById("carred").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("carblack").style.display = "none";
}
} else if($(this).next().attr("checked")){
    document.getElementById("carblack").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("carblue").style.display = "block";
}else{
       document.getElementById("carblack").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("carred").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("carblue").style.display = "none";        }
});

$('#car2').change(function () {

if($(this).attr("checked")){
     if($(this).prev().attr("checked")){
     document.getElementById("carblack").style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById("carred").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("carblue").style.display = "none";

    }else{
    document.getElementById("carblue").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("carblack").style.display = "none";
    }
 } else if($(this).prev().attr("checked")){
    document.getElementById("carblack").style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById("carred").style.display = "block";
 }else{
       document.getElementById("carblack").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("carred").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("carblue").style.display = "none";        }
});​
```